# Could not load file or assembly 'Ninject.Web, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget-package

I am working MVC5 project. I want use MVC forum Nuget package  using package manager console . installed   package manger console . after trying to Run project i am getting Error Like this

```
Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Ninject.Web, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7' could not be loaded.




=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Ninject.Web, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/TIckmarksportal/MVC5_Full_Version/Inspinia_MVC5/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\TIckmarksportal\MVC5_Full_Version\Inspinia_MVC5\bin
Calling assembly : mvcForum.Web, Version=1.5.1.60520, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\TIckmarksportal\MVC5_Full_Version\Inspinia_MVC5\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\Tickmarks\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Ninject.Web, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Tickmarks/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/d4d6aff4/6a77f817/Ninject.Web.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Tickmarks/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/d4d6aff4/6a77f817/Ninject.Web/Ninject.Web.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/TIckmarksportal/MVC5_Full_Version/Inspinia_MVC5/bin/Ninject.Web.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/TIckmarksportal/MVC5_Full_Version/Inspinia_MVC5/bin/Ninject.Web/Ninject.Web.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Tickmarks/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/d4d6aff4/6a77f817/Ninject.Web.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Tickmarks/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/d4d6aff4/6a77f817/Ninject.Web/Ninject.Web.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/TIckmarksportal/MVC5_Full_Version/Inspinia_MVC5/bin/Ninject.Web.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/TIckmarksportal/MVC5_Full_Version/Inspinia_MVC5/bin/Ninject.Web/Ninject.Web.EXE.
```

I am try installed Higher version not Working? how to fix? before install MVC forum its Working . after install It showing Error Like this.

Answer (score 1):

The MVCForum package has reference to Ninject.Web, but this package doesn't install together with MVCForum. You need to install the Ninject.Web package by yourself.